# Sorting 3d arrays in python as per grid

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, datagrid, mayavi

I have grid points in 3d and I would like to sort them based (x,y,z) using python (if possible avoiding loops)..

For example if the input is,
(1,2,1), (0,8,1), (1,0,0) ..
then output should be
(0,8,1), (1,0,0), (1,2,1)..

---

Sorry for this side track but I am actually doing is reading from a file which has data in following way:
x y z f(x) f(y) f(z)..
what I was doing was following:

```
def fill_array(output_array,source_array,nx,ny,nz,position):
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        for k in range(nz):
            output_array[i][j][k] = source_array[i][j][k][position]
nx = 8
ny = 8
nz = 8

ndim = 6

x = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
y = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
z = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
bx = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
by = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
bz = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))

data_file = np.loadtxt('datafile')
f = np.reshape(data_file, (nx,ny,nz,ndim))
fill_array(x,f,nx,ny,nz,0))
fill_array(y,f,nx,ny,nz,1)
fill_array(z,f,nx,ny,nz,2)
fill_array(fx,f,nx,ny,nz,3)
fill_array(fy,f,nx,ny,nz,4)
fill_array(fz,f,nx,ny,nz,5)
```

This was working fine when data was arranged (as explained previously) but with file written not in order it is creating problems with plot later on. Is there are better way to do this ? Of course I only want to arrange x,y,z and then associate functional value f(x),f(y),f(z) to its right position (x,y,z)

two updates
1) i am getting following error when I use sorted with either x,y,z,fx,fy,fz or f.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

2) i need it in that specific way because I am using mayavi then for contour3d

Comment: If the points are sequences (lists or tuples) of three numbers in a list, named say `points`, just use `sorted(points)`.

Comment: Thanks. can you please check the updated question and give your suggestions.

Comment: The updated question is a completely different one. SO threads aren't supposed to be live chat... I suggest making a new question for this tangent. In the new question, show your source data (the file) and the target format (for Mayavi), and show how you're currently trying to get from A to B.

Comment: @kwinkunks
First I don't think it is completely tangent. Question is still about ordering of data as I know the plot works fine with ordered data.
Next, I can only ask once in 90 mins.

Comment: @kwinkunks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848595/plotting-a-3d-data-read-from-a-file-using-mayavi

Answer (score 4):

The built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) does what you want:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2, 1), (0, 8, 1), (1, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(a)
[(0, 8, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. can you please check the updated question and give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[sorted][1]`.

```
In [71]: sorted(a)
Out[71]: [(0, 8, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1)]
```

more precisely

```
In [70]: sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))
Out[70]: [(0, 8, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1)]
```

`key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2])`
at this step we are `sorting` `list` at `0th` `1st` and `2nd` element of `tuple`

Comment: You don't need to supply the `key` function, because that's what `sorted()` would do by default.

Comment: @martineau trying to tell more precisely.

Comment: Thanks. can you please check the updated question and give your suggestions.