# Plotting a 3d data read from a file using mayavi

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, grid, mayavi

I have a data file in the following format:

```
x y z f(x) f(y) f(z)
```

I want to plot it using contour3d of mayavi:

```
def fill_array(output_array,source_array,nx,ny,nz,position):
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                output_array[i][j][k] = source_array[i][j][k][position]

nx = 8
ny = 8
nz = 8

ndim = 6

x = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
y = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
z = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
fx = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
fy = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
fz = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))

data_file = np.loadtxt('datafile')
f = np.reshape(data_file, (nx,ny,nz,ndim))
fill_array(x,f,nx,ny,nz,0))
fill_array(y,f,nx,ny,nz,1)
fill_array(z,f,nx,ny,nz,2)
fill_array(fx,f,nx,ny,nz,3)
fill_array(fy,f,nx,ny,nz,4)
fill_array(fz,f,nx,ny,nz,5)

f2 = fx**2 + fy**2 + fz**2
plot_data = mlab.contour3d(f2)
mlab.colorbar(plot_data,title='f2',orientation='vertical')
mlab.savefig('f.png',magnification=5)
```

This was working fine when data is arranged in a order (x,y,z) grid data. But with file written not in order it is creates plot which doesn't match the one with ordered data (which I know is correct). What could be the reason/solution ?

Of course I only want to arrange x,y,z and then associate functional value f(x),f(y),f(z) to its right position (x,y,z).

Comment: The indentation of your code is messed up, it's unclear what the purpose is of `bx`, `by`, and `bz`, plus `fx`, `fy`, and `fz` are undefined. Despite all that, my guess is you need to add a `data_file = np.sort(data_file)` statement after the `data_file = np.loadtxt('datafile')` line.

Comment: @martineau  I am sorry, I mixed up. bx, by, bz are fx, fy, fz. Can you please tell me the error in indentation ?? Meanwhile I will try np.sort

Comment: Can your `x`, `y` and `z` values be rearranged to create an evenly spaced grid, or are your points unevenly sampled?

Comment: @ali_m it is evenly spaced grid

Comment: @martineau np.sort doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should print the contents of `data_file` after the `np.sort()` to see what it's doing that's not right.

Comment: @martineau 
I did that. It actually sorts x values (which is already ordered for test case).  It would be helpful for me to sort in a order of y and if y are equal sort with respect to z. Always carrying f(x), f(y), f(z) with its corresponding x,y,z

Comment: I inquired thus about `np.sort` with order. But then reshape commands gives an error saying `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`. Is there a better way to make this plot ??

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
I added the following just after reading the file (rest code remaining same):

```
data_file = np.loadtxt('datafile', 
dtype=[('x',float),('y',float),('z',float),('fx',float),('fy',float),('fz',float)])
data_file = np.sort(data_file,order=['z','y'])
f = np.array(data_file).reshape(nx,ny,nz)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Where is `dtype` used in your answer?

Comment: @martineau: 
If I not wrong, it is just used to assign data types to variables

Comment: I asked because there don't appear to be any further references to it in your answer. Trying commenting the line that defines it out and see if it has any effect.